# Python file I/O with Tkinter

Tags: python, io, tkinter

I'm trying to open a .txt file with Python. I'm trying to fill a Tkinter text widget with the files contents.

However with the following snippet, when I try to open the files contents and put it in a the text widget **self.Te**, nothing happens. Any clues?

Snippet:

```
    self.Open = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(initialdir='C:')

    text_file = open(self.Open, "r")
    # self.Te is a text widget
    self.Te.insert('1.0', text_file.read())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a working example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from Tkinter import *
from tkFileDialog  import askopenfilename   

class App:
    def __init__(self, master):
        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack()

        self.button = Button(frame, text="QUIT", command=frame.quit)
        self.button.pack(side=BOTTOM)

        self.text = Text(frame)
        self.text.pack(side=TOP)

        self.choosen = askopenfilename(initialdir='~')
        self.text.insert(END, open(self.choosen).read())        

root = Tk()
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

See also Text widget method documentation:

- http://www.pythonware.com/library/tkinter/introduction/x8369-methods.htm

> ... Insert text at the given position (typically `INSERT` or `END`) ...